# JQuery onBlur script still not interacting with method

Tags: jquery

It looks like I did not manage in getting  my Spring method to work together with Jquery script. Here is the method

```
  @RequestMapping(value="vsfill.html", params = "accountId", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String getAccount(@RequestParam("accountId") String accountId) throws JSONException {
    logger.debug("getAccount() accountId "+accountId);

    String json = null;
    String _json = null;

            User user = idmClient.getUser(accountId);

                HashMap hm = new HashMap();
                hm.put("accoountId", user.getAccountId());
                //hm.put("givenName", user.getGivenName());
                hm.put("callingName", user.getCallingName());
                hm.put("email", user.getEmail());
                json = JsonUtils.javaToStr(hm);


    return json;
}
```

}

The script

```
      $("#person").blur(function() {
  var accountId =$('#person').val();
  $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'vsfill.html?accountId='+accountId,
  dataType: 'json',
  data: (accountId),
  success: function(data) {


      if (data!=null&&data!='') {
            $('#responsableName').val(data.callingName);
            $('#resposableMail').val(data.Mail);
        }
      }});
   });
```

I'm a newbie.

Comment: `resposableMail` > Typo here. `logger.debug("getAccount() accountId "+accountId);` -> This gets loggeed?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
url: 'vsfill.html?accountId='+accountId,
dataType: 'json',
data: (accountId),
```

woth

```
url: 'vsfill.html',
dataType: 'json',
data: {accountId: accountId},
```

Answer (score 0):

1. .val() will not work with
   Labels......They work with input
   element only. So i think
   `$('#responsableName').val(data.callingName);`
   is wrong.

   You should try:
   `$('#responsableName').text(data.callingName);`

   source:
   [http://api.jquery.com/text/][1]

   [1]: http://api.jquery.com/text/

---

1. Your data is not send to server
   properly because it does not holds
   any name. It must have a name like
   "person=Bob". To send this way, you
   have to send your data as: {
   Key:Value } format in jquery. So
   change data portion => data: {
   accountID: accountID }

---

Edit: try the following code:

```
$("#person").blur(function() {
    var accountId =$('#person').val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'vsfill.html',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {accountId:accountId},

      success: function(data) 
      {    
          if (data!=null && data!='') 
          {
                $('#responsableName').text(data.callingName);
                $('#resposableMail').text(data.email);
          }
      }
   });   
});
```

most probably there were some syntax error (like extra braces), for which the code didn't work.

Comment: Does the accountId really get value from person field? With these modifications it still does not work.